# Azure SQL DB: Slow, anyway I can make it fast?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We have Azure Sql Database. It was working fine for last 18 months or so. but from last 1 week we found some operation are slower than usual. We have CSV uploaded to one table and it used to take less than 20 sec for 70K records, but in last week or so, now even a 20-30K records take about 45 or more sec and usually get `timed out`.

I just check and found that our table only have 1.1 M records (that is average record count it has since start) and on peek usage it reached 1.5-1.8 in past and used to work fine. But not this time? Is there any way I can find out what gets slower? or how can I improve it. My client do not have budget to get any external help, and I am not an DB expert, just a regular programmer with some knowledge.

EDIT:
In Last 2 days even a Simple query such as `select count(*) from tbl` on main table starts taking 7-8 secs.

Nothing has change in 7 days or 7 months or a year. It was working great before.

Comment: How are you uploading the CSVs to the table? Are there a lot of indexes? Do you have an example of the data?

Comment: @Charleh The data is simple Name and Address of person. I am using SQlBulkCopy to copy to a Temporary Table and then Transfer from Temp Table to Main Table.

Comment: Last year I tried to move my service to Azure SQL DB.  It was a disaster.  Azure SQL DB is not fit for even moderate load scenarios.  My suggestion would be to stay away from it if you are running a productive app.

Comment: @AllenKing I agree with you, but we are already on Azure and using it for year. this is second time it goes so worse.First time it automatically get okay. Even this time it seems Hardware node issues, but nowhere I can find and fix problem. even their support is paid and my client do not have much money.

Comment: Its a multi tenant environment. The performance depends on so many factors.  We faced exactly same issues.  Even a simple select statement on a table with 2000 entries would time out.